# Understanding Right Apply

Tags: haskell, applicative

For a List, why does `right apply (*>)` behave as repeating and appending the second argument `n` times, where `n` is the length of the first argument?

```
ghci> [1,2,3] *> [4,5]
[4,5,4,5,4,5]
```

Comment: Are you sure, its not `>>`?

Comment: @thefourtheye `*>` is `>>` if the applicative in question is also a monad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*>` operator is defined, by default, as

```
xs *> ys = id <$ xs <*> ys
```

which in turn translates, by default, to

```
const id <$> xs <*> ys
```

That is, it replaces each element of `xs` with `id` to get `xs'` and then calculates `xs' <*> ys`. `[]` is a `Monad` instance, where `(=<<) = concatMap`. One of the laws of `Applicative` lays out the relationship between `Applicative` and `Monad` instances:

```
pure = return
fs <*> as = fs `ap` as = fs >>= \f -> as >>= \a -> f a
```

For lists, this is

```
fs <*> as = [f a | f <- fs, a <- as]
```

So `*>` for lists is ultimately determined by the `Monad` instance.

Note that there is another very sensible `Applicative` instance for lists, which is made available through a newtype in `Control.Applicative`:

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList [a]
instance Applicative ZipList where
  pure = repeat
  (<*>) = zipWith ($)
```

Comment: In the end, the effect is that each element of `[1,2,3]` is replaced with `[4,5]`, giving `[[4,5],[4,5],[4,5]]`, which is then flatted with `concat` into `[4,5,4,5,4,5]`. If you define this yourself as `xs *> ys = concat (map (const ys) xs)`, you can show that this is equivalent to the given definition of `(*>)`, and also to `(>>)`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, I need to finish that off properly and reword some things, but I'm feeling oddly giddy at the moment, so it's hard to focus. If you want to take the last step or two from `<*>` to `*>`, go ahead and edit.

Comment: I tried that and it was difficult so I stopped when I saw your answer. :D It's a rather circuitous path.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think there's most likely also a connection to be made to tree grafting monads via some sort of morphism. Tree grafting seems a much more natural expression of this than list `concatMap`.

Comment: This is a good example of monads for substitution, yes. I'm just not sure how to word it concisely.

Comment: Interesting, @Rein. But, `concat (map (const ys) xs)` won't work with `Maybe a`. So, is `dfeuer`'s generic definition considered better - `const id <$> xs <*> ys` out of its genericity? I admit that I don't know how `*>` is defined - whether it's defined in general for all usages or per implementing class.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, it has a default definition, and all implementations are expected to be semantically the same as that (except possibly more defined). But some types (e.g., `Data.Sequence`) are able to work magic and give more efficient `*>` implementations than the default.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Rein Henrichs version works in general if you rewrite it a little bit to use functions that are more generic: `join (fmap (const ys) xs)`